# How to request an applicationID using YARN REST API

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Trying to execute the spark program using YARN RESTAPI in HORTONWORKS 2.5
i have followed this link: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/kbentry/28070/starting-spark-jobs-directly-via-yarn-rest-api.html

Issue I'm facing is :
In the 5step: Request an application ID from YARN

```
curl -ikvu "knoxuser:knoxpwd" -X POST "https://$KNOX_SERVER:8443/gateway/default/resourcemanager/v1/cluster/apps/new-application"
```

Error:

> - About to connect() to $KNOX_SERVER port 8443 (#0) * Trying 53.244.194.234... connected * Connected to $KNOX_SERVER (53.244.194.234) port 8443 (#0) * successfully set certificate verify
>     locations: * CAfile: none CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/ * SSLv3, TLS
>     handshake, Client hello (1): * error:140770FC:SSL
>     routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol * Closing connection
>     #0 curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Where do I find the url or I'm going wrong in the url part in the command?

Please let me know, it would be great help to me.